# Create Custom coin using pallet_balance of Substrate

Tags: substrate-node-template, pallet

So a Quick Question ?
I am having trouble customizing the existing `pallet_balance` to create a new `crypto coin` in my own image .I am using `Substrate-Node-Template`.

Comment: in what part of it have you faced an issue or have a question? adding `pallet_balances` to the runtime already means you have created your `crypto coin` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the name, decimals, or other properties of the chain (Polkadot SDK codebase refers to them as "[Additional loosely-typed properties of the chain](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/1c435e91c117b877c803427a91c0ccd18c527382/substrate/client/chain-spec/src/chain_spec.rs#L404C1-L408C3)") you can do so in the chain_spec file of your node, which is generally located at `./node/src/chain_spec.rs`.

You can define the properties like this:

```rust
let mut properties = sc_chain_spec::Properties::new();
properties.insert("tokenSymbol".into(), "YOUR_TOKEN_SYMBOL".into()); 
properties.insert("tokenDecimals".into(), <YOUR TOKEN DECIMALS>.into());
properties.insert("ss58Format".into(), 42.into());
```

and then call the `.with_properties(properties)` function on the `ChainSpec::Builder` to set your token properties.

Reference implementation can be seen [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/1c435e91c117b877c803427a91c0ccd18c527382/templates/parachain/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L114C1-L119C52) in the Polkadot repo.

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot. So in chain_spec where should i customize to give the blockchain a new total supply

Comment: in genesis, your total supply/issuance is the sum of all balances of endowed accounts in the `balances` config

Comment: @Md.RaisulIslamRony you can define the prefunded accounts in the `chain_spec` file like [this](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/2ad9b78c7b56434c8036d1447120f4566583e54e/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L96C1-L109C7) and fund them from `BalancesConfig` in `RuntimeGenesisConfig` like [this](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/2ad9b78c7b56434c8036d1447120f4566583e54e/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L141C1-L144C5). Different types of impls can be found in different chains, I'm just referencing the node template.

Comment: Also pls consider upvoting and accepting the answer if you found it useful.